# Trigger to ensure unique values in column

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have to write a trigger to ensure unique entries in column `account` of table `accounts`:

```
   create table accounts (id serial, account int4 default 0);
```

I tried to write my trigger like this:

```
create function x_6 () returns trigger as '

begin
    IF row(new.account) is distinct from row(OLD.account) THEN
       return NEW;

    ELSE
       raise notice '' Entries are not unique! '';
    END IF;
end;
'
language 'plpgsql';
```

Or:

```
create function x_6 () returns trigger as '                         
begin
    IF (new.account <> OLD.account) THEN
       return NEW;

    ELSE
       raise notice ''  Entries are not unique ! '';
    END IF;
end;
'
language 'plpgsql';
```

And then

```
 create trigger x_6t before insert on accounts for each row execute procedure x_6();
```

When I try to insert something:

```
insert into accounts(account) values (20);
```

I get an error in either case:

```
ERROR:  record "old" is not assigned yet
DETAIL:  The tuple structure of a not-yet-assigned record is indeterminate.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "x_6" line 3 at if
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

This is absolutely wrong way. You should not to use triggers for this purpose, you should to use *unique indexes*.

```
CREATE TABLE foo(a int PRIMARY KEY, b int);
-- column b has only unique values
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON foo(b);
```

Your code has more than one issue:

- bad identifiers - konto instead account
- it is table trigger - you has no any access to data there - PostgreSQL triggers are different than MSSQL
- If you use row trigger, where there is possible access to record data, then OLD has different meaning than you expect. It is value of record before change - and this value is defined only for UPDATE or DELETE operations - and it is undefined for INSERT, because there previous value of record doesn't exist.

Comment: Without deep knowledge of possible race conditions, locking and transaction isolation levels you cannot do it with trigger. And somebody who has these knowledges probably don't use triggers because trigger based solution should be slow